# Error in RGEOSDistanceFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, "rgeos_distance") : negative length vectors are not allowed

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, r, distance, rgeos

What does the error in the title mean? I'm fairly new to GIS and can't understand which negative length vectors R is talking about? Here is what I'm doing:

I have a csv of lat/long locations of certain points and a multiPolygon Shapefile of buildings in a particular city . I want to find the nearest polygon to each point. First I have converted the points and polygons to planar projections by the following code:

```
##BUILDINGS DATA

buildings<-readOGR("buildings.shp")
buildings<- spTransform(buildings, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=45 +a=6377299.151
                                        +b=6356098.145120132 
                                        +towgs84=295,736,257,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs "))

##LATITUDES/LONGITUDES DATA

locations<-read.csv("20190712033434-47083-data.csv")

locations <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = locations, data = locations,
                                    proj4string = 
                                      CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
locations<- spTransform(locations, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=45 +a=6377299.151
                                        +b=6356098.145120132 
                                        +towgs84=295,736,257,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs "))
```

Then I find the minimum distance using the following formula:

```
minimum_distance<- apply(gDistance(locations, buildings,byid=TRUE),2,min)
```

But it gives me the error:

```
Error in RGEOSDistanceFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, "rgeos_distance") : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: is it possible some of the points are inside the polygons?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Hard for us to track down without your data, and nothing obviously wrong with the code. Subset `locations` and `buildings` and see if its down to a particular item in one or the other.